# Doctrine default cli-config.php location

Tags: doctrine-orm, command-line-interface

I would like to change the location of the doctrine cli-config.php file as well as possibly change it's name -- the first request is more important.

Any ideas???

Comment: You must remove the file? I don't know if is what you need but you can make a copy via post command in the composer files, let me know if you need more info. Hope this help

Comment: What is so specific about this file? Is it Doctrine internal? If so, do you have a link? What is your final goal?

Comment: This file has to be in the root directory of your project  - same as composer - or in a /config directory -- I would prefer to have it in a /scripts/cli-doctrine.php location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the doctrine CLI directly, this is not possible.

You can see this by having a look at the relevant [source code](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/900b55d16afdcdeb5100d435a7166d3a425b9873/bin/doctrine.php#L32):

```
$directories = array(getcwd(), getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config');
$configFile = null;
foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    $configFile = $directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cli-config.php';
    if (file_exists($configFile)) {
        break;
    }
}
```

It only ever checks for `cli-config.php` and `config/cli-config.php`.

---

The alternative is to implement a CLI based on the [Symfony Console component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html) (which is what the Doctrine CLI is based on) yourself, and pull in the Doctrine commands. This allows you to avoid having `cli-config.php` altogether at the cost of having to put in a not-insignificant amount of work. You can find the details of this approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28385755/975165).

Answer (score 0):

Exists another one approach. You can add in custom location file, for example cli.php(with your own file name). Than add in this file something like that:

```

```
<?php
// cli.php
// where your entityManager is created
require_once "bootstrap.php";

$helperSet = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
    'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($entityManager)
));

\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::run($helperSet);
```

```

And you can run this file from where you want like `php cli.php`.